# Can I personally create a StackExchange spinoff?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, clone

Before you mark it as a duplicate, I'm specifically asking if I'm allowed to make one, myself, and add it to the pool of already existing sites.
Is it possible? I'd want it to be based entirely off of the building of custom personal computers.

Comment: What is a "spinoff" in this context? You want to build a new site, based on SE model?

Comment: @ShadowWizard well, I guess not quite that. I'd like to add to the official list of stackexhange sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard didn't see that one, thanks

Comment: OK, so the answer is trivial: yes you are allowed, and it's explained in the dupe how to do that. :)